how can I create a live video feed using espnow protocol?
I have two esps, one is a esp32, and the other is a esp32s3_eye, I have a tft display connected to the esp32, and i want the camera from the esp32s3_eye to send a live video feed to the screen, using espnow. I already have some code for the transmitter and receiver, however I just get random pixels on the screen, most of its static, but there are 3 lines at the top, and 1 line in the middle that flash random colours. When I unplug the camera, the flashing pixels stop, and continue if its plugged back in. The other data transmitting such as the float and int where just for debugging.  enter image description here tft display
// receiver


#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Define the pins used
#define TFT_CS        5
#define TFT_RST       4  // Or set to -1 and connect to ESP32 RST
#define TFT_DC        2

Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// Structure example to receive data
// Must match the sender structure
typedef struct struct_message {
    char a[32];
    int b;
    float c;
    bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

// Constants for image data handling
const int chunkSize = 1024; // Define a reasonable chunk size
uint8_t imgBuffer[chunkSize];
int imgOffset = 0;
int totalImgSize = 320 * 240; // QVGA image size
bool imgReceived = false;

// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const esp_now_recv_info *info, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  // If the received data length is the same as the struct, it's our struct
  if (len == sizeof(myData)) {
    memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
    Serial.print("Bytes received: ");
    Serial.println(len);
    Serial.print("Char: ");
    Serial.println(myData.a);
    Serial.print("Int: ");
    Serial.println(myData.b);
    Serial.print("Float: ");
    Serial.println(myData.c);
    Serial.print("Bool: ");
    Serial.println(myData.d);
    Serial.println();
  } else {
    // Otherwise, it's image data
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      imgBuffer[imgOffset++] = incomingData[i];
      if (imgOffset == chunkSize) {
        // Process this chunk of data
        int x = 0; // Calculate x position
        int y = 0; // Calculate y position
        tft.drawRGBBitmap(x, y, (uint16_t*)imgBuffer, 320, 240); // Draw one line at a time
        imgOffset = 0; // Reset offset for next chunk
      }
    }
    if (imgOffset == totalImgSize) {
      imgReceived = true;
      Serial.println("image recived");
      imgOffset = 0;
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  // Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Initialize the TFT display
  tft.init(240, 320);  // Init ST7789 240x320
  tft.setRotation(1);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Waiting for image...");

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Register callback function for receiving data
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
}

void loop() {
  if (imgReceived) {
    tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
    tft.setCursor(0, 0);
    tft.println("Image received!");
  } 
}

//Transmitter


#include <esp_now.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_camera.h"

#define CAMERA_MODEL_ESP32S3_EYE
#include "camera_pins.h"

// REPLACE WITH YOUR RECEIVER MAC Address
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0xfc, 0xe8, 0xc0, 0x7d, 0xff, 0x50}; // esp32 with spi screen

typedef struct struct_message {
  char a[32];
  int b;
  float c;
  bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a struct_message called myData
struct_message myData;

esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;

// callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}

void setup() {
  // Init Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set device as a Wi-Fi Station
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  // Register for Send CB to get the status of Transmitted packet
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
  
  // Register peer
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 0;  
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;
  
  // Add peer        
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }

  // Initialize the camera
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sccb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_QVGA; // 320x240
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG; // for streaming
  config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_WHEN_EMPTY;
  config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_PSRAM;
  config.jpeg_quality = 12;
  config.fb_count = 1;

  if (psramFound()) {
    config.jpeg_quality = 10;
    config.fb_count = 2;
    config.grab_mode = CAMERA_GRAB_LATEST;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.fb_location = CAMERA_FB_IN_DRAM;
  }

  // Camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Capture photo
  camera_fb_t *fb = esp_camera_fb_get();

  if (!fb) {
    Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Camera capture successful");

    // Send image in chunks
    int chunkSize = 240; // ESP-NOW max payload size
    int numChunks = fb->len / chunkSize + (fb->len % chunkSize != 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
      int offset = i * chunkSize;
      int len = min(chunkSize, (int)(fb->len - offset));
      esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, fb->buf + offset, len);

      if (result == ESP_OK) {
        Serial.printf("Chunk %d sent with success\n", i);
      } else {
        Serial.printf("Error sending chunk %d\n", i);
      }

      delay(30); // small delay to avoid overwhelming the receiver
    }

    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
  }

  // Set values to send
  strcpy(myData.a, "THIS IS A CHAR");
  myData.b = random(1, 20);
  myData.c = 1.2;
  myData.d = false;

  // Send message via ESP-NOW
  esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *)&myData, sizeof(myData));

  if (result == ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Sent with success");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error sending the data");
  }

}

I tried using web sockets, ble, esp now, however, i cant get any of them to work, theres little information online for this, and whatever there is doesn't seem it work.

ESPNOW is a low bandwidth, unreliable protocol. It’s not designed for video streaming, which requires high bandwidth.

@romkey, thank you for commenting and helping, what would you suggest I do instead?, thanks

I'm sorry, but this is a very broad question and not one well suited for discussion in Stack Overflow comments. You might try Reddit. But generally video is streamed over a raw TCP connection or over HTTP.
